# Kendo UI Grid Row Height when it is initialized

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I use the Kendo UI grid in my project to present my data. 
I have a trouble about the its row height. When the grid is initialized; the row seems very odd. I tried to give some informations about the grid's back. The console screen contains some informations about the grid's initialization. You can glance through the enclosed picture.
[image]

Comment: can you share your grid code?

Comment: I solved this problem. Many thanks. You can find my answer in "answer" section of this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.k-grid tr td {
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0px 0 1px 1px;
border-color: #c5c5c5;
```

}